# Kill std::thread while reading a big file

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, fopen

I have a `std::thread` function that is calling `fopen` to load a big file into an array:

```
void loadfile(char *fname, char *fbuffer, long fsize)
{
  FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
  fread(fbuffer, 1, fsize, fp);
  flose(fp);
}
```

This is called by:

```
std::thread loader(loadfile, fname, fbuffer, fsize);
loader.detach();
```

At some point, something in my program wants to stop reading that file and asks for another file. The problem is that by the time I delete the `fbuffer` pointer, the `loader` thread is still going, and I get a race condition that trows an exception.

How can I kill that thread? My idea was to check for the existance of the `fbuffer` and maybe split the `fread` in small chunks:

```
void loadfile(char *fname, char *fbuffer, long fsize)
{
  FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
  long ch = 0;
  while (ch += 256 < fsize)
  {
     if (fbuffer == NULL) return;
     fread(fbuffer + ch, 1, 256, fp);
  }
  fclose(fp);
}
```

Will this slow down the reading of the file? Do you have a better idea?

Comment: Just let the thread run, you don't have to use the result after all.

Comment: You cannot kill a detached tread: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt if I delete `fbuffer` while the thread is running, the program crashes.

Comment: Why do you even have a pointer to such a buffer? Why doesn't the thread allocate, fill and then forward the buffer? Still, I never said you should delete the buffer. If you use reference counting, just set the pointer to null and forget about the thread that's running in the background. When the thread finishes, it will destroy its copy of the pointer and the buffer will be released automatically.

Answer (score 5):

You should avoid killing a thread at all costs. Doing so causes evil things to happen, like resources left in a permanently locked state.

The thread must be given a reference to a flag, the value of which can be set from elsewhere, to tell the thread to *voluntarily* quit.

You cannot use a buffer for this purpose; if one thread deletes the memory of the buffer while the other is writing to it, very evil things will happen.  (Memory corruption.)  So, pass a reference to a boolean flag.

Of course, in order for the thread to be able to periodically check the flag, it must have small chunks of work to do, so splitting your `fread`s to small chunks was a good idea.

256 bytes might be a bit too small though;  definitely use 4k or more, perhaps even 64k.

Answer (score 0):

Killing threads is usually not the way to go - doing this [may lead to leaked resources, critical sections you cannot exit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_exit) and [inconsistent program state.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx)

Your idea is almost spot-on, but you need a way to signal the thread to finalize. You can use a boolean shared between your thread and the rest of your code that your thread reads after every read, and once it is set, stops reading into the buffer cleans up the file handles and exits cleanly.

On another note, handling the deletion of pointers with owning semantics by yourself is most of the time frowned upon in modern C++ - unless you have a very good reason not to, I'd recommend using the stl fstream and string classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need proper thread synchronization. The comments about resource leaks and the proposal by @Mike Nakis about making the thread exit voluntarily by setting a boolean are *almost* correct (well, they're *correct*, but not complete). You need to go even farther than that.

You must ensure not only that the loader thread exits on its own, you must **also** ensure that it has exited before you delete the buffer it is writing to. Or, at least, you must ensure that it isn't ever touching that buffer in any way after you deleted it. Checking the pointer for null-ness does not work for two reasons. First, it doesn't work anyway, since you are looking at a copy of the original pointer (you would have to use a pointer-pointer or a reference). Second, and more importantly, even if the check worked, there is a race condition between the `if` statement and `fread`. In other words, there is no way to guarantee that you aren't freeing the buffer while `fread` is accessing it (no matter how small you make your chunks).

At the very minimum, you neeed two boolean flags, but preferrably you would use a *proper* synchronization primitive such as a condition variable to notify the main thread (so you don't have to spin waiting for the loader to exit, but can block).

The correct way of operation would be:

1. Notify loader thread
2. Wait for loader thread to signal me (block on cond var)
3. Loader thread picks up notification, sets condition variable *and never touches the buffer afterwards*, then exits
4. Resume (delete buffer, allocate new buffer, etc)

If you do not insist on detaching the loader thread, you could instead simply `join` it after telling it to exit (so you would not need a cond var).